# SQL error "Incorrect syntax near '=' " - classic ASP /SQL server

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I am running the following SQL query on a SQL Server database (via MS Access and ODBC)

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   D.DOC_TYPE, D.DOC_REF, 
   COUNT(D.GUID) AS Total, 
   SUM(IIF(I.TEAM = 'OPS1', 1, 0)) AS OPS1, 
   SUM(IIF(I.TEAM = 'OPS2', 1, 0)) AS OPS2, 
   SUM(IIF(I.TEAM = 'OPS3', 1, 0)) AS OPS3, 
   SUM(IIF(I.TEAM = 'OPS4', 1, 0)) AS OPS4, 
   SUM(IIF(I.TEAM = 'OPS5', 1, 0)) AS OPS5, 
   SUM(IIF(I.TEAM = 'OPS6', 1, 0)) AS OPS6, 
   SUM(IIF(I.TEAM = 'OPS7', 1, 0)) AS OPS7, 
   SUM(IIF(I.TEAM = 'OPS8', 1, 0)) AS OPS8, 
   SUM(IIF(I.TEAM = 'OPS9', 1, 0)) AS OPS9, 
   SUM(IIF(I.TEAM = 'OPS10', 1, 0)) AS OPS10, 
   SUM(IIF(I.TEAM Not Like 'OPS*', 1, 0)) AS OtherTeams
FROM 
   dbo_DOCUMENT AS D 
INNER JOIN 
   dbo_INTRAY AS I ON I.DOC_GUID = D.GUID
WHERE 
   D.DOC_TYPE like 'GIM*'
   AND I.FILE_SYSTEM = 'B' 
   AND I.MAIL_STATUS IN ('N', 'NT')
GROUP BY 
   D.DOC_TYPE, D.DOC_REF;
```

It runs fine. I have pasted this into a Classic ASP page variable as below

```
SQL =   "SELECT DISTINCT D.DOC_TYPE, D.DOC_REF, COUNT(D.GUID) AS Total, " & _
        "SUM(IIF(I.TEAM='OPS1',1,0)) AS OPS1, " & _
        "SUM(IIF(I.TEAM='OPS2',1,0)) AS OPS2, " & _
        "SUM(IIF(I.TEAM='OPS3',1,0)) AS OPS3, " & _
        "SUM(IIF(I.TEAM='OPS4',1,0)) AS OPS4, " & _
        "SUM(IIF(I.TEAM='OPS5',1,0)) AS OPS5, " & _
        "SUM(IIF(I.TEAM='OPS6',1,0)) AS OPS6, " & _
        "SUM(IIF(I.TEAM='OPS7',1,0)) AS OPS7, " & _
        "SUM(IIF(I.TEAM='OPS8',1,0)) AS OPS8, " & _
        "SUM(IIF(I.TEAM='OPS9',1,0)) AS OPS9, " & _
        "SUM(IIF(I.TEAM='OPS10',1,0)) AS OPS10, " & _
        "SUM(IIF(I.TEAM Not Like 'OPS*',1,0)) AS OtherTeams " & _
        "FROM DOCUMENT AS D INNER JOIN INTRAY AS I ON I.DOC_GUID = D.GUID " & _
        "WHERE D.DOC_TYPE like 'GIM*' " & _
        "AND I.FILE_SYSTEM='B' AND I.MAIL_STATUS IN ('N', 'NT') " & _
        "GROUP BY D.DOC_TYPE, D.DOC_REF;"
```

However, when run in the ASP page, it reports the following error;

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e14'
>
> Incorrect syntax near '='.
>
> /bactu/IWStats/GIM1.asp, line 49

Line 49 is where the recordset is opened.

Any clues? I've even tried putting `Response.Write(SQL)` into the output page and copied the SQL from there into Access and it runs fine.

Comment: What version of sql server? You can't use IIF in sql server until sql server 2012.

Comment: Not sure if this was a typo on purpose or not but in your non ASP query, you have underscores between dbo and tablename. `FROM dbo_DOCUMENT AS D INNER JOIN dbo_INTRAY`   I would also try to wrap the "D.GUID" like "D.[GUID]"

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using MSAccess query syntax, but your error is coming back with a SQL Server error.  Try using TSQL syntax instead.  Try this:

```
SQL = "SELECT DISTINCT D.DOC_TYPE, D.DOC_REF, COUNT(D.GUID) AS Total, " & _
    "SUM(CASE WHEN I.TEAM='OPS1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OPS1, " & _
    "SUM(CASE WHEN I.TEAM='OPS2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OPS2, " & _
    "SUM(CASE WHEN I.TEAM='OPS3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OPS3, " & _
    "SUM(CASE WHEN I.TEAM='OPS4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OPS4, " & _
    "SUM(CASE WHEN I.TEAM='OPS5' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OPS5, " & _
    "SUM(CASE WHEN I.TEAM='OPS6' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OPS6, " & _
    "SUM(CASE WHEN I.TEAM='OPS7' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OPS7, " & _
    "SUM(CASE WHEN I.TEAM='OPS8' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OPS8, " & _
    "SUM(CASE WHEN I.TEAM='OPS9' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OPS9, " & _
    "SUM(CASE WHEN I.TEAM='OPS10' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OPS10, " & _
    "SUM(CASE WHEN I.TEAM Not Like 'OPS%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OtherTeams " & _
    "FROM DOCUMENT AS D INNER JOIN INTRAY AS I ON I.DOC_GUID = D.GUID " & _
    "WHERE D.DOC_TYPE like 'GIM%' " & _
    "AND I.FILE_SYSTEM='B' AND I.MAIL_STATUS IN ('N', 'NT') " & _
    "GROUP BY D.DOC_TYPE, D.DOC_REF;"
```

CASE is the TSQL equiv to IIF, and TSQL uses % as a wildcard for LIKE instead of *.